# PYTHON win32gui clearing background

Tags: python, project, win32gui

I am new here it's my first post. Please be understanding. I have a problem with clearing background after drawing a rect on screen. Here is my code:

```
def draw_rectangle(left, top, right, bottom):
    hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    hdc = win32gui.GetDC(hwnd)   
    rect = (left, top, right, bottom)
    edge_style = win32con.BDR_RAISEDOUTER | win32con.BDR_SUNKENINNER
    flags = win32con.BF_RECT
    win32gui.DrawEdge(hdc, rect, edge_style, flags)    
    win32gui.InvalidateRect(hwnd, None, True)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc)
```

I am using InvalidateRect but it's not working. I dont't know what is wrong with this code and if it is even possible to restore background with this library. If you  have any idea, please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.